# Maui Blazor Hybrid .net8.0-ios publish error

Tags: ios, maui, publish

I am breaking my brain on this one, I am trying to publish my MAUI app to IOS from visual studio. This is the first time I am getting this error

> Xamarin.VisualStudio.Progress.ProgressReportService Information: 0 :
> !Cannot create an IOS archive 'MyProject'. Process cannot be executed
> on XMA server. The "Unzip" task failed unexpectedly.
> System.NotSupportedException: The given path's format is not
> supported.    at
> System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.EmulateFileIOPermissionChecks(String
> fullPath)    at
> System.IO.Directory.InternalCreateDirectoryHelper(String path, Boolean
> checkHost)    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.CompressionHelper.TryDecompressUsingSystemIOCompression(TaskLoggingHelper
> log, String zip, String resource, String decompressionDir) in
> /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Decompress.cs:line
> 200    at
> Xamarin.MacDev.CompressionHelper.TryDecompress(TaskLoggingHelper log,
> String zip, String resource, String decompressionDir, List`1
> createdFiles, String& decompressedResource) in
> /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Decompress.cs:line
> 104    at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.Unzip.ExecuteLocally() in
> /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Tasks/Unzip.cs:line
> 61    at Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks.Unzip.Execute() in
> /Users/builder/azdo/_work/1/s/xamarin-macios/msbuild/Xamarin.MacDev.Tasks/Tasks/Unzip.cs:line
> 43    at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext()

Steps to reproduce

1. Completed Development on MAUI blazor project
2. Successfully Rebuild Project - DEBUG
3. Successfully Rebuild Project - RELEASE
4. Set project properties and iOS signage for publish
5. Start to build archive file for iOS to publish, then error pops up
6. I have switched on diagnostics on my build output and it seems somewhere it concats the path incorrectly and is also compiling ANDROID items even when I have selected iOS to be published. This is where the error occures during build

Error:

Ditto: 2024-02-05T17:50:53.1156162+02:00 - Creating output 'obj\Release\net8.0-ios\ios-arm64\ipa\Payload\MyApp.app**\C:\T**\MYdIR\MyApp\Platforms\Android\google-services.json'...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\17.2.8004\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(391,3): warning : The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: Please include what you already tried and steps to reach the issue.

Comment: @fbernardo please see the steps included. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelBrooks The issue could be caused from too long path inside zip file, please try to Right-click My Computer > Properties. Click Advanced System Settings > Environment Variables. Select the TEMP variable and click Edit and put a short path, eg c:\tmp.